# How to score Solr autosuggestions?

Tags: search, solr, autosuggest

I've setup Solr for autosuggestions. It needs to be able to suggest phrases and handle spelling errors. So far, I'm using a normally tokenized field for spelling suggestions (works fine) and a copy of the same field without tokenization to search on with wildcards for autosuggestion (e.g. *searchterm*). This also works ok, but due to wildcards, the scoring is always 1 for each document. In addition, normal scoring wouldn't actually make sense here. The natural way to score would be based on how many results would the suggested phrase generate if it were a search term itself. Something similar to what Solr's spellchecker is using. I don't think this is possible out of the box, but I have no real clue.
Any ideas on how to achieve this? Or at least improve it?
It's important that the suggestions remain full phrases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TermsComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent) with `terms.prefix=searchterms` or `terms.regex=.*searchterm.*` for suggestions. It returns the frequency of found terms.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this isn't exactly what you are looking for but if you have search log from the users of your search, you can use frequency as one of the boosting or just doing ordering by the frequency.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is actually what I'll have to do. I'll have a scheduled task to feed the search statistics to Solr every once in a while. Is that the correct way to do it? Still, I was initially misunderstanding my own problem and thus phrased the question wrongly. The way I asked, Artem's answer is correct (and I marked it as such). The TermsComponent does exactly what I asked for. Sorry for the mess :(